# How to remove timestamp and leave date only (Postgres/Python)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I'm going through as follows:

```
  for index, row in my_dataframe.iterrows():
        cursor.execute(""" UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COLUMN1 = %s, 
        COLUMN2 = %s WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_COLUMN, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = %s AND COLUMN1 IS NULL""",
                                        (row['VALUE_A'],
                                         row['VALUE_B'],
                                         row['DATE_C']
                                         ))
```

The date in `row['Date_C']` is coming across as a Timestamped value YYYY-MM-DD H24..etc :

How do I remove this so I only have it display the YYYY-MM-DD ?

Comment: 1) It means the column type for `DATE_C` is `timestamp(tz)`. If want it to be `date` then change it. 2) If you want to keep it `timestamp(tz)` then cast it as `DATE_C::date` .

Comment: Hello @AdrianKlaver - Thank you. Could you perhaps give an example in this case? Ideally, if I could manipulate the row['DATE_C'] variable that would be ideal.

Comment: Provide the table description for the table you are updating as update to your question. Also the data type for the column in the dataframe.

Comment: Why are you storing date values in a `varchar` (or `text`)  column? That is a huge mistake to begin with.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name: We agree. Its not what I wanted, but the process I'm doing is complex. If I left DATE_COLUMN as a DATE or TIMESTAMP datatype - the entire code breaks.. it starts complaining about me having to do casting and what-not... its a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By timestamp, if you mean unix timestamp string, then

Import DateTime Library at the top of your script

```
import datetime as dt
```

Then do this

```
for index, row in my_dataframe.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(""" UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COLUMN1 = %s, 
    COLUMN2 = %s WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_COLUMN, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = %s AND COLUMN1 IS NULL""",
                                    (row['VALUE_A'],
                                     row['VALUE_B'],
                                     dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(row['DATE_C']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                                     ))
```

if it is not a unix timestamp, then please provide data type of `row['DATA_C']`

Comment: Oh wow - thank you! .. its just an ORACLE date field of type YYYY-MM-DD H24:MM:SS - I just need to get rid of the H24:MM:SS.

Comment: Still not clear what the data type is. ORACLE date field? Can you show the piece of code from where you assign `row['DATE_C']`

Comment: Hello nazim. Thank you so much for your support. I'll endeavour to send you the code, but your comment was of great help.